# SQL INSERT why does it add only the first element from array?

Tags: php, arrays, database

I have a loop `foreach` in it, I execute queries. I have an associative `array`, the key is the name of the column. If id is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, only the first request is performed `true`, and all the other `false`. If you put an `AUTO_INCREMENT` in db, all queries are executed, but in a cascade style.

---

```
$namePhones = ["phone_1", "phone_2", "phone_3", "phone_4", "phone_5"];
$jsonPhones = $userInfo;
$jsonPhones = array_splice($jsonPhones, 0, 1);
$phones = new stdClass();

$phonesCount = count($jsonPhones[0]);    
 foreach ($jsonPhones[0] as $key => $value) {
   if($key < $phonesCount){
      $phones->{$namePhones[$key]} = $jsonPhones[0][$key];
    } else { return; }
  }
  $phonesDB = json_decode(json_encode($phones), true);

//$phonesDB//this is array
// Array
// (
//    [phone_1] => 1
//    [phone_2] => 2
//    [phone_3] => 3
//    [phone_4] => 4
//)

    foreach ($phonesDB as $key => $value) {
        $queryInsertPhones = 
            "INSERT INTO 
               `phones_users` ($key) 
            VALUES  ($value)";
            $resultPhones =  mysqli_query($con, $queryInsertPhones); 
    }
```

---

```
 cascade style.
 +--------------------------------+
 |id | phone_1 | phone_2 | phone_3|
 |---+---------+---------+--------|
 |1  |  1      | ---     |  ---   |
 |---+---------+---------+--------|
 |2  |  ---    | 2       |  ---   |
 |---+---------+---------+--------|
 |3  |  ---    | ---     |  3     |
 +---+----------------------------+

 I want this.
  +--------------------------------+
 |id | phone_1 | phone_2 | phone_3|
 |---+---------+---------+--------|
 |1  |  1      | 2       |  3     |
 |---+---------+---------+--------|
 |2  |  ---    | ---     |  ---   |
 +---+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Because you are looping through the array, and in each iteration you insert the data into a new row.

Comment: First of all this is bad practice. If most people have 1 phone number you end up with a table which is 50% nulls

Comment: how can this be solved? @Mehdi Bounya

Comment: this is a dynamic array @apokryfos

Comment: The table is not dynamic though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that you execute query per key and not for all keys.

This is how you need to do it:

```
// Make a variables that will conaints all keys and values seprate by comma
$keyList = '';
$keyValue = '';
// Add key and value to their variable with comma
foreach ($phonesDB as $key => $value) {
    $keyList .= '`'.$key.'`,';
    $keyValue .= '\''.$value.'\',';
}
// Remove the last comma
$keyList = substr($keyList, 0, -1);
$keyValue = substr($keyValue, 0, -1);
// Build the SQL query
$queryInsertPhones = 
    "INSERT INTO 
       `phones_users` ($keyList) 
    VALUES  ($keyValue)";
// Execute the query
$resultPhones =  mysqli_query($con, $queryInsertPhones);
```

I guess this code is in the main loop if you want more than one insert.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. A user can send from one to five phones. the array itself is formed. I added some code. @Almog

Comment: @МишаПодлевских your code is executing a query every run of the loop instead of taking the key and build the query for all keys. In my answer, I show to you how to build the query for all keys.

Comment: Thank you! It is work, and i understood this! @Almog

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a slight difficulty seeing exactly what you are doing, but generally when you are inserting into an SQL database you should specify a where clause to specify the the row you want to insert in based on the primary key for that row. If you are trying to add data to a row that has already been inserted then you should use update instead of insert.

The simplest solution for you would be to have a nested loop. The inside loop should go through a single row and get all the phone numbers for the row then insert all of the values at once. Your outer loop should iterate across all rows.